# MVC Site Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture

I am building an online product using MVC4.

Currently, I structured the project into the obvious xx.Web, xx.Data, xx.Services

Here is the set of questions that I like to get your opinion on:

1- For the data layer, I am going to use the Repository pattern. I have created an .dbml that will host my Database tables. Should I create for each table a class or should should I use the classes generated by the .dbml?
2- Where For the Repository interfaces, where should I place them? in a different project xx.Data.Common or in a folder inside xx.Data?

3- Where does Error logging and Security code goes ? I have created an xx.Web.Common project for that?

Is there any guidelines for a common architecture for an MVC application? I mean I did some research but you get over flooded with tones of extensions like Ninject, etc...

I just want to implement best practices. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- For the data layer, I am going to use the Repository pattern. I have created an .dbml that will host my Database tables. Should I create for each table a class or should should I use the classes generated by the .dbml?

If you build your web from beginning, I would suggest you use [Code First with Entity Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) because Linq2Sql has not evolved anymore.

You don't need to map 1 : 1 from your model with your database table, focus on designning domain model firs, database will be generated automatically. Also, needless to map 1 : 1 from repositoty with table. You need to understand Repository pattern with Aggregate and Aggregate Root

> 2- Where For the Repository interfaces, where should I place them? in a different project xx.Data.Common or in a folder inside xx.Data?

Should have one more dll called: xx.Domain to put your domain models and repositories interface. With this way, xx.Domain is core assembly which does not depend on any other assemblies.

> 3- Where does Error logging and Security code goes ? I have created an xx.Web.Common project for that?

Should have more dll called: xxx.CrossCuttings for logging and security.

Use IoC container to make loose couple between layers and testability.

Not common guideline for MVC Architecture, but try to keep your code simple, maintainable and flexible is the key.

Answer (score 1):

There is http://sharparchitecture.net/  for a out-the-box best practice starting template. However I think most of the solutions I seem on-line are over engineered and aimed at enterprise level sites.

If your just making a  **online product** then a simple one solution with 2-3 layers will be sufficient. Start with the simplest solution possible. You can always add to it or make a new layer when/if the need arises.

Comment: That's what I am thinking. Maybe implementing the Repository Pattern and Ninject would be a good start. The thing is you read tons and tons of solutions but you never see the advantage of it in a real situation. Grasping Theoretical things will not teach how or when to implement these features. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: +1 for taking the simplest route first. A good approach imho is to focus on maintainability of your code so it's easy to add new things.